# Hybrid Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a application in android and ios both,can i synchronize same data in realtime using firebase?

I have made firebase projects for both but how to make both ios and android point to one firebase datbase, i have tried getreferncefromurl() but shows error that mismatch url

I also tried putting getinstance(url) but dint worked

code :-

```
package com.example.rushabh123453.n123_real;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView condition;
    Button sunny,foggy;

   /* String url="https://iosprojle-456.firebaseio.com/";
    FirebaseApp ref = new FirebaseApp(url);*/


    DatabaseReference mRootRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference conditionref=mRootRef.child("condition");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        condition=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_cond);
        sunny=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sunny);
        foggy=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_foggy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        conditionref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String text  =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                condition.setText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


 sunny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         conditionref.setValue("Sunny");
     }
 });

        foggy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                conditionref.setValue("foggy");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: To connect an Android app to the same Firebase project, create an Android app in that project from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview. That will give you a `google-services.json` to add to your Android app, which then contains all information that it needs to find the project on the Firebase servers.

Comment: I want to connect ios app to the same realtimedatabse that of android

Comment: The same applies, except that you'll get a `google-service.plist` that you add to your XCode project. With that the Android app and the iOS app will be looking at the same database. We gave an example of such a cross-platform app in our [zero to app talk at Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01M_hZav9Gw).